# Object required error enabling/disabling combobox/checkbox based on a combobox

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I'm working on a sheet that has a repeating series of one combobox linked to one other combobox and a checkbox.

The first box has four selectable options.
If either of the first two options is selected, both the second combobox and the checkbox should be disabled.
If either of the last two options is selected, the second box and checkbox should both become enabled.

When I first set up this code, everything worked. I accidently threw myself into an endless loop and had to start with the "Excel recovered" worksheet, which scrubbed all my controls.

I re-did the controls. Now when I open the workbook, I have to click through fifty (yes, no joke, five-zero) instances of an "object required" run-time error. The same thing happens when I close the workbook. But when I clear all the errors, the code runs. Using "Option Explicit" gives me a "variable not defined" error.

I can't identify any variables which need defining.

```vb
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 Or ComboBox1.ListIndex = 3 Then
        ComboBox6.Enabled = True
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    Else: ComboBox6.Enabled = False
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This is for one instance. I have twenty-five of these repeated, one after the other, in my project.

Comment: The two errors are related.  If you are not using the proper syntax to the object, then it assumes it is a variable and not defined.  There isn’t a lot to go on here to see how you set up the user form or initialized it.  When researching, it is good to find a tutorial instead of that “one thing missing” tip.  Here is one on user forms https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/

Comment: Make a copy of your workbook and delete all the controls except for the first set - get that working first. Even if `Option Explicit` causes you problems you should use it: there's a reason it gets recommended here.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can avoid most of that replicated code by using a naming scheme which allows you to associate your sets of 3 controls: eg see below. Then you can have one single procedure which performs the checks, given the first combobox as an argument.

e.g. (you can probably come up with more-meaningful names based on what your controls actually represent):

```txt
ComboBox1 - ComboBox1_2 - chkComboBox1
ComboBox2 - ComboBox2_2 - chkComboBox2
ComboBox3 - ComboBox3_2 - chkComboBox3
```

Then your code can look like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ProcessChange ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    ProcessChange ComboBox2
End Sub

'process the supplied combobox value and set properties of
'  any related controls
Sub ProcessChange(cmbo As ComboBox)
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = cmbo.Value = 2 Or cmbo.Value = 3
    Me.OLEObjects(cmbo.Name & "_2").Object.Enabled = en
    Me.OLEObjects("chk" & cmbo.Name).Object.Enabled = en
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your input. I replicated your code on a brand new worksheet where it is the only code on the book and I'm still getting a very similar problem. I named my objects exactly as you had them for testing, and it works fine except for when I open the workbook. I still get Run-time error 1004, "The item with the specified name wasn't found." Debug places the error only on the second combobox, which was what was happening in my original code. Interestingly enough, this only happens when I open the workbook with the second combobox enabled. If I save with the box disabled, no error.

Comment: In my original code this happened whether the second box was enabled or not. And for some reason, the checkboxes never seem to have this problem. Nor does the first combobox. It seems that for some reason VBA can't identify the second combobox in any iteration as an object, yet it never seems to have a problem identifying any of the other objects. I am very curious as to why.

Comment: "Interestingly enough, this only happens when I open the workbook with the second combobox enabled. If I save with the box disabled, no error." Scratch that. I just played around with it some more and realized that on my test project I only get the error every other time I open it, regardless of what's enabled or disabled.